# How do I draw a circle in pgfplots that uses data coordinates?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw a circle with radius specified in data coordinates. But I don't get that. Here's a circle with radius "5" but its data coordinates radius appears to be only 0.05. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% pgfplots package manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-0.7,xmax=0, xlabel={$x$}, xtick={-1,-0.9,...,0}, minor xtick={-1,-0.95,...,0}, 
    ymin=0.3,ymax=1.0, ylabel={$y$}, ytick={0, 0.1,...,1}, minor ytick={0, 0.05,...,1},
    samples=500,domain=-1:0,
    grid=both,
    title={\large shapes on axis}]
    
  \addplot[blue]({x}, {1-x*x} );
  \draw (axis cs:-0.4,0.5) circle [radius=5];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alway set the `compat` level when using PGFPlots. By setting it to something new, the `axis cs` is default inside `axis` and the radius of a circle is as expected.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-0.7,xmax=0, xlabel={$x$}, xtick={-1,-0.9,...,0}, minor xtick={-1,-0.95,...,0}, 
    ymin=0.3,ymax=1.0, ylabel={$y$}, ytick={0, 0.1,...,1}, minor ytick={0, 0.05,...,1},
    samples=500,domain=-1:0,
    grid=both,
    title={\large shapes on axis}]
  \addplot[blue]({x}, {1-x*x} );
  \draw (-0.4,0.5) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot with circle]

Comment: Huh -- I don't get why it works, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing to get. The PGFPlot simply behaves different dependent on the `compat` level (`\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`).

Answer (score 1):

This is just an additional answer to explain more the behavior given in the (correct) accepted answer.

`pgfplots` has a very nice backward compatibility structure - when the author changes something, or even fixes some bug, it does so under a "compatibility level" mechanism.

For example, the very first versions of the package had a very loose positioning of axis ticks. Christian Feuersänger fixed this, but now there were a problem: all the drawing already done in old documents would change, creating painful unexpected work to the authors. So the new behavior, even if it's the arguably correct one, has to be manually enabled, with, in this case `compat=1.3` - which says that you do not want compatibility with versions earlier than this.

At version 1.11, the default coordinate system in the axis environment has been changed so that the coordinate system for `addplot` and `draw` were the same; before (as you saw) they were different (details in the very fine manual).

Finally, if you do not use a compat level, `pgfplots` complains loudly with a warning... That nobody ever read ;-)